# How to have null values for datetime parameter in ssrs reports?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, report

I have three parameters on my report: `StartDate`, `EndDate` and `AccountID`.

I want to make `StartDate` and `EndDate` as optional values. How can I achieve this? I see that there is no option for selecting allow blank values for the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Well, there should be. There is a flag "Allow null value", see [this post](http://arcanecode.com/2010/07/13/adding-query-parameters-to-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-reports/) at step 10.